# Convert C++ custom unit type to primative Java type with SWIG

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have C++ code that I am attempting to provide Java bindings using SWIG.

```
struct meters_t : public boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::length> {};
```

I am hoping to try replace all references of `meters_t` to just be a `double` or `Java.lang.Double`.

I've attempted the following in my SWIG interface `.i` file:

```
%typemap(jstype) meters_t "java.lang.Double"
%typemap(jtype) meters_t "java.lang.Double"
%typemap(jni) meters_t "jdouble"
...
// Duplicated for const, const&, &
%ignore meters_t
%include "my_include.h"
```

However I am currently getting a typecast error

```
error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'meters_t *' to 'jdouble'
error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from `jdouble` to `meters_t *`
```

Does anyone have any advice to correct this? I am quickly losing hope that the idea of converting `meters_t` into a simple `double` will be possible :/

**UPDATE:**
I have also added the following

```
%typemap(javain) meters_t "$javainput"
```

Which enables the Java bindings to be built, however when I attempt to use the Java bindings (on a different `struct` that takes `meters_t` as a constructor arg, it immediately throws an error

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

**UPDATE 2.0**

I now have `meters_t` SWIG wrapped. My new problem is a class with a boost default argument, and I'm getting the elusive `Syntax error in input(3).` error

```
Foo(meters_t meters = meters_t{ 0.0 * boost::units::si::meters });
```

Comment: In your Update 2.0, what's your line supposed to do? I can't parse it too.

Comment: It's a constructor definition for my class `Foo`, with an argument of `meters_t`, defaulting to 0 meters. `meters_t` is wrapped to a Java double, so I imagine the problem relates to `boost::units::si::meters`, but sadly I don't have much more information to the error than what is currently posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have started on the right track with [typemaps](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Typemaps.html). These are crucial for converting types between C++ and Java. But the errors suggest that SWIG is having trouble automatically converting between `meters_t` and `jdouble`.

You might need to provide *custom* typemaps to handle this conversion explicitly. You need to provide a way for SWIG to understand how to convert `meters_t` to `jdouble` and vice versa.

Try and implement `%typemap(in)` and `%typemap(out)` for `meters_t`. These typemaps will define how to convert a `meters_t` object to a Java `double` when passing from C++ to Java, and vice versa.

SWIG has limited support for parsing complex [default arguments](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_default_args)]. One solution is to simplify the default argument in the SWIG interface file, or provide an overloaded version of the constructor without the default argument for SWIG to wrap.

In your [SWIG interface file](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn47), implement the typemaps:

```cpp
%typemap(in) meters_t {
    // Code to convert from jdouble to meters_t
}

%typemap(out) meters_t {
    // Code to convert from meters_t to jdouble
}

// For the constructor issue
%ignore Foo::Foo(meters_t);
%extend Foo {
    Foo() {
        return new Foo(meters_t{0.0 * boost::units::si::meters});
    }
}
```

You  need to fill in the conversion logic based on how `meters_t` can be converted to and from a `double`.

```bash
Java Side                     JNI Bridge                    C++ Side
──────────                     ──────────                    ────────
   jdouble                         |                     meters_t Object
   (double)                        |                           |
     |                             |                           |
     |      [ JNI Conversion ]     |                           |
     |---------------------------->|                           |
     |                             |    Construct meters_t     |
     |                             |  using jdouble value      |
     |                             |<--------------------------|
     |                             |                           |
     |                             |      Extract double       |
     |                             |  value from meters_t      |
     |                             |-------------------------->|
     |                             |                           |
     |<----------------------------|                           |
     |                             |                           |
```

---

Regarding "`Code to convert from jdouble to meters_t`", when converting from Java to C++, you will receive a Java `double` (represented as `jdouble` in C++ JNI code). You need to convert this to a `meters_t` object.
Assuming `meters_t` can be constructed or assigned from a `double`, the typemap might look like this:

```cpp
%typemap(in) meters_t {
    $1 = meters_t($input * boost::units::si::meter);
}
```

In this typemap:

- `$1` is the placeholder for the C++ argument (in this case, `meters_t`).
- `$input` represents the input from Java (a `jdouble`).
- The expression `$input * boost::units::si::meter` constructs a `meters_t` object from the Java double, assuming that `meters_t` can be initialized in this way.

---

For "`Code to convert from meters_t to jdouble`":

When converting from C++ to Java, you need to extract a `double` value from your `meters_t` object:

```cpp
%typemap(out) meters_t {
    $result = (jdouble)$1.value();
}
```

In this typemap:

- `$1` is the placeholder for the C++ `meters_t` object.
- `$result` is the JNI representation of the Java type you are mapping to (`jdouble` in this case).
- `$1.value()` is a hypothetical method or way to extract the `double` value from a `meters_t` object. You will need to replace this with the actual method or approach for extracting the numeric value from your `meters_t` type.

Make sure that `meters_t` can be constructed from a `double` and has a method to extract its value as a `double`. If not, you will need to adapt the code to suit the actual interface of `meters_t`.
These typemaps assume that `boost::units::si::meter` is the appropriate unit for conversion. Adjust if necessary based on your specific implementation of `meters_t`.

---

> Unfortunately this has not corrected my current outstanding issue. I have actually already attempted what you suggested with ignoring the constructor and providing another.
> `C:\my_project\src\inc\foo.h(line of the foo ctor): Syntax error in input(3)`. Given the error is in the `foo.h`, I feel like SWIG is unable to parse the default argument for whatever reason, where ignoring the code will not help; I imagine SWIG reading foo.h is independent of any directives in the SWIG Interface file?

The error `Syntax error in input(3)` does indeed suggest that SWIG is having trouble parsing the C++ code in your header file, specifically the constructor with the default argument in `foo.h`. That can happen when the syntax or constructs used in the C++ code are too complex or unfamiliar to SWIG.

If possible, simplify the constructor in the C++ header file. That means removing or altering the default argument in a way that SWIG can understand. For example, you could split the constructor into two: one without arguments and another taking a `meters_t` argument, handling the default case in the implementation rather than in the declaration.

```cpp
// Original:
// Foo(meters_t meters = meters_t{ 0.0 * boost::units::si::meters });

// Simplified:
Foo();
Foo(meters_t meters);
```

Create an overloaded version of the constructor specifically for SWIG. That version would not have the complex default argument. Use [SWIG's `%ignore` directive](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_rename_ignore) to ignore the problematic constructor and expose only the simplified version.

In your SWIG interface file:

```cpp
%ignore Foo::Foo(meters_t meters = meters_t{ 0.0 * boost::units::si::meters });

%extend Foo {
    Foo() {
        return new Foo(meters_t{0.0 * boost::units::si::meters});
    }
}
```

You can also use [`%inline`](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn43) to provide an alternative, SWIG-friendly version of the problematic code directly in the interface file. That allows you to keep the original C++ code as is but provide a simplified version for SWIG to process.

```cpp
%inline %{
class Foo {
    public:
    Foo() : Foo(meters_t{0.0 * boost::units::si::meters}) {}
    Foo(meters_t meters) { /* Constructor implementation */ }
};
%}
```

The key is to create an interface that SWIG can parse without losing the functionality you need in the Java bindings.

---

> Yeah, modifying the `ctor` to provide a `Foo()` and `Foo(meters_t meters)`, where moving the initialisation of `Foo::meters (meters = meters_t{ 0.0 * boost::units::si::meters })` to `Foo.cpp` corrects the issue.
> I would really much prefer to SWIG wrap the code in question without having to alter the source code.
> I feel like I am missing a boost header, but I have added the includes used in the `.h` file into my SWIG interface `%module MyModule { //some boost headers }`. In short, SWIG does not know what `boost::units::si::meter` is when it reads `Foo.h`!?

I agree: you would prefer not to modify the original C++ source code to accommodate SWIG. The issue (where SWIG does not recognize `boost::units::si::meter`) is likely due to SWIG's limited understanding of complex C++ constructs, especially from libraries like [Boost](https://www.boost.org/).

Including Boost headers in the SWIG interface file is a good start. However (again), SWIG might not fully understand or parse complex Boost constructs. Make sure you include the necessary Boost headers in your SWIG interface file, similar to how they are included in your C++ header files (though this might not always be feasible with complex templated types like those in Boost).

```cpp
%module MyModule
%{
#include "foo.h"
#include <boost/units/systems/si/length.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/prefixes.hpp>
%}
```

As mentioned before, use `%ignore` to exclude the problematic constructor from SWIG's processing.
Then, either use [`%extend`](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_adding_member_functions) to define a SWIG-friendly version of the constructor or [`%rename`](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_rename_ignore) to expose a different, simplified constructor to Java.

```cpp
%ignore Foo::Foo(meters_t meters = meters_t{ 0.0 * boost::units::si::meters });
```

As a last resort, if SWIG struggles with the Boost types, consider creating a wrapper class in C++ that presents a simpler interface to SWIG. That wrapper would internally handle the Boost types and complexities, exposing only SWIG-friendly types and methods.

- Create a `FooWrapper` class that simplifies the interface for SWIG.
- Inside `FooWrapper`, manage the complex Boost interactions, exposing simpler methods for SWIG.

```cpp
class FooWrapper {
public:
    FooWrapper() : foo(0.0 * boost::units::si::meters) {}
    explicit FooWrapper(double meters) : foo(meters * boost::units::si::meters) {}

private:
    Foo foo;
};
```

Then in the SWIG interface file:

```cpp
%include "FooWrapper.h"
```

The goal remains to find a balance between preserving the original C++ source code and providing SWIG with a form it can understand. In that context, creating a simplified interface or wrapper for SWIG can often be a practical solution, especially when dealing with complex libraries like Boost.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I appreciate the nice breakdown here! :) 

Unfortunately this hasn't corrected my current outstanding issue. I have actually already attempted what you suggested with ignoring the constructor and providing another. 

`C:\my_project\src\inc\foo.h(line of the foo ctor): Syntax error in input(3).`

Given the error is in the `foo.h`, I feel like SWIG is unable to parse the default argument for whatever reason, where ignoring the code won't help; I imagine SWIG reading `foo.h` is independent of any directives in the SWIG Interface file?

Comment: Yeah, modifying the ctor to provide a `Foo()` and `Foo(meters_t meters)`, where moving the initialisation of `Foo::meters` (`meters = meters_t{ 0.0 * boost::units::si::meters }`) to  `Foo.cpp` corrects the issue. I would really much prefer to SWIG wrap the code in question without having to alter the source code.

I feel like I am missing a boost header, but I have added the includes used in the `.h` file into my SWIG interface `%module MyModule { //some boost headers }`

In short, SWIG doesn't know what `boost::units::si::meter` is when it reads `Foo.h`

Comment: @bleuj I have edited the answer to address your comments.